# Raspberry PI 4 not booting, ACT LED blinks 4 times, boot recovery won't help

Tags: boot-issues, bootloader

My RPI4 just stopped booting. Green ACT led blinks 4 times and the monitor stays dark, hard drives won't start.

What I've tried:

1. I installed a fresh Raspberry PI OS to another card, that booted up, so the SD card slot is OK.
2. I installed EEPROM BOOT RECOVERY to a fresh SD with Raspberry PI Imager, ran it, then switched to the original SD and I get stuck to this screen with 00000004 error:

[image]

Is there anything else I could try that would save me from having to reinstall everything?

Comment: Most of us would break out our backup. Do you have one?

Comment: Don't have backups of this one :/

Comment: @any_h Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue, but even a reformat of the OS didn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: @matthewsteele I wasn't able, had to start from the beginning